# GLB file not loading in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

My glb file wont show up inside my thee.js world. I have followed all the documentations and tutorals but nothing works. the world loads and evry thing works fine its just that the moddle dose not appear. Plaese help me i am on a jurnay to make a game that is compleatly in html/js and i am decently well exerpienced in js. Please keep the code as original as possible and good luck. I have only used stack overflow once so sorry if this is a bad description. I the file is in the same folder as the code file. I know that it is a long snipbit of code but i wanted to make sure that you could see all the code incase it is more than just my importing. I dont know what else to say so sorry i am just stalling a bit. If you can please explain in vary vary vary simple terms what was wrong and how you fixed it. I have to keep stalling becouse there is too much code. I dont know how much longer i have to keep up this typeing. Once again soo sory for stalling i just cant describe this much. I realy relye on stack overflow and wold love if you helped ne.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
       body { margin: 0; }
       #info {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 100;
      display:block;
       }
    </style>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/build/three.module.js",
          "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/examples/jsm/",
          "cannon-es": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cannon-es@0.20.0/dist/cannon-es.min.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="info">0</div>
    <script type="module">
      import * as THREE from "three";
      import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
      import { Clock } from "three";
      import { PointerLockControls } from "three/addons/controls/PointerLockControls.js";
      import * as CANNON from "cannon-es";
      import { OBJLoader } from "three/addons/loaders/OBJLoader.js";
      import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
      const score = document.getElementById("info");
      let points = 0;
      let colide = false;
      let checkK = false;
      let Name;
      let boddy;

      const clock = new Clock();
      const world = new CANNON.World();
      world.gravity.set(0, -9.82, 0);
      const loader = new GLTFLoader();

      const physicsMaterial = new CANNON.Material();
      const physicsContactMaterial = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(
        physicsMaterial,
        physicsMaterial,
        { friction: 0.4, restitution: 0.0 }
      );

      


      world.addContactMaterial(physicsContactMaterial);

      function createCannonBox(size, position, masss) {
        this.shape = new CANNON.Box(
          new CANNON.Vec3(size.x / 2, size.y / 2, size.z / 2)
        );
         this.body = new CANNON.Body({
          mass: masss,
          material: physicsMaterial,
        });
        this.body.addShape(this.shape);
        this.body.position.copy(position);
        world.addBody(this.body);
        return this.body;
      }
      function createCannonBall(size, positionn, masss) {
         this.shape = new CANNON.Sphere(size);
         this.body = new CANNON.Body({
          mass: masss,
          material: physicsMaterial,
          shape: this.shape
        });
        this.body.position.copy(positionn);
        world.addBody(this.body);
        return this.body;
      }
      function createCannonKnot(size, position) {
        const Sshape = new CANNON.Sphere(size);
        const Sbody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1, material: physicsMaterial });
        Sbody.addShape(Sshape);
        Sbody.position.copy(position);
        world.addBody(Sbody);
        return Sbody;
      }
      function CreateTrimesh(geometry) {
        const vertices = geometry.attributes.position.array;
        const indices = Object.keys(vertices).map(Number);
        return new CANNON.Trimesh(vertices, indices);
      }

      const groundShape = new CANNON.Plane();
      const groundBody = new CANNON.Body({
        mass: 0,
        shape: groundShape,
        material: physicsMaterial,
      });
      groundBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(
        new CANNON.Vec3(1, 0, 0),
        -Math.PI / 2
      );
      world.addBody(groundBody);

      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
      );
      camera.position.z = 3;
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      const Oloader = new OBJLoader();

      const concreteTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
        "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/wall.jpg"
      );
      const controls = new PointerLockControls(camera, document.body);

      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
      const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00,
        map: concreteTexture,
        clearcoat: 0.1,
      });

      const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      cube.castShadow = true;
      scene.add(cube);
      
      // here is my attempt

      loader.load( '../free_1975_porsche_911_930_turbo.glb', function ( gltf )
    {
      const sword = gltf.scene;  // sword 3D object is loaded
      sword.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
      sword.position.y = 1;
      scene.add(sword);
    } );

      

      const cubeBody = new createCannonBox(
        new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1),
        new CANNON.Vec3(0.5, 4, 0),
        1
      );

      const Sgeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 40, 20);

      const ball = new THREE.Mesh(Sgeometry, material);
      ball.castShadow = true;
      scene.add(ball);
      const ballBody = new createCannonBall(
        0.5,
        new CANNON.Vec3(0.5, 20, 0),
        1
      )


      

      const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      cube2.castShadow = true;
      scene.add(cube2);
      const cubeBody2 = new createCannonBox(
        new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1),
        new CANNON.Vec3(0, 2, 0),
        0
      );

      const groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
        map: concreteTexture,
        clearcoat: 1,
        clearcoatRoughness: 1,
        metalness: 0.9,
      });

      const groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 100, 100);
      const ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry, groundMaterial);
      ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
      scene.add(ground);

      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x87ceeb);

      const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
      light.position.set(0, 15, 5);
      light.castShadow = true;
      scene.add(light);
      const light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
      scene.add(light2);

      light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
      light.shadow.camera.far = 40;
      light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1025;
      light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1025;
      light.shadow.radius = 4;

      renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

      light.shadow.camera.left = -10;
      light.shadow.camera.right = 10;
      light.shadow.camera.top = 10;
      light.shadow.camera.bottom = -10;
      light.shadow.bias = -0.002;

      camera.position.y = 1;

      var keys = {};
      window.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
        keys[ev.key] = true;
      });
      window.addEventListener("keyup", function (ev) {
        keys[ev.key] = false;
      });
      window.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
        if (ev.code == "KeyE") {
          checkK = !checkK;
        }
      });

      const moveVector = new THREE.Vector3();
      const setVector = new CANNON.Vec3();

      camera.rotation.order = "YXZ";

      const initialCubePosition = cube.position.clone();
      const initialCubePosition2 = cube2.position.clone();
      const initialBallPosition = ball.position.clone();

      const resetInterval = 2.0;
      let lastResetTime = clock.elapsedTime;

      function check() {
        cubeBody2.addEventListener("collide", function (e) {
          colide = true;
         // name = cube;
          //boddy = cubeBody;
        });
        cubeBody.addEventListener("collide", function (e) {
          Name = cube;
          boddy = cubeBody;
        });
        ballBody.addEventListener("collide", function (e) {
          Name = ball;
          boddy = ballBody;
        });
      }

      function go() {
        if (keys.w) moveVector.z -= 0.1;
        if (keys.s) moveVector.z += 0.1;
        if (keys.a) moveVector.x -= 0.1;
        if (keys.d) moveVector.x += 0.1;
        if (keys.c) moveVector.y -= 0.1;
        if (keys.v) moveVector.y += 0.1;
        if (checkK && colide && keys.e) (checkK = false), (colide = false), (boddy.mass = 1);
        if (keys.m) controls.lock();

        moveVector.multiplyScalar(0.6);
        camera.translateX(moveVector.x);
        camera.translateZ(moveVector.z);
        camera.translateY(moveVector.y);

        if (colide && checkK) {
          boddy.mass = 1;
          boddy.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);
          Name.position.copy(camera.position);
          Name.translateX(moveVector.x);
          Name.translateY(moveVector.y);
          Name.translateZ(moveVector.z - 3);
          boddy.position.copy(Name.position);
        }
        score.innerText = checkK;
        cube.position.copy(cubeBody.position);
        cube.quaternion.copy(cubeBody.quaternion);
        ball.position.copy(ballBody.position);
        ball.quaternion.copy(ballBody.quaternion);
        cube2.position.copy(cubeBody2.position);
        cube2.quaternion.copy(cubeBody2.quaternion);
        cubeBody2.position.copy(camera.position);
        if (clock.elapsedTime - lastResetTime >= resetInterval) {
          lastResetTime = clock.elapsedTime;
        }
      }

      function animate() {
        const delta = clock.getDelta();
        world.step(delta);
        check();
        go();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }

      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, model is loading but its not presing in Camera's frustums.
add OrbitController and check where the model is loading.
If you provide the output image and console error, then it will be more understandable about the issue

Comment: I added the orbit controls but they won't focus on the sword even if I make it a new variable outside of the function and assign it inside the function.